# HTML tag remove from

Tags: r

I have written code for downloading files from FTP sites ! here's my basic start of code:

```
filenames = getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
#filenames <- strsplit(filenames,"<!></><>")
filenames <- gsub("<(.|\n)*?>","", filenames)
#gsub("<.*?>", filenames)
filenames = unlist(filenames)
filenames
```

and I am getting output something like this

> "\n\n \n  Index of /data\n \n \nIndex of /data\nNameLast
> modifiedSize\nParent Directory   - \n2D/24-Feb-2021 15:57    -
> \n3DRefl/13-Oct-2020 16:30    - \n3DRhoHV/13-Oct-2020 16:30    -
> \n3DZdr/13-Oct-2020 16:30    - \nProbSevere/13-Oct-2020 16:30    -
> \nRIDGEII/11-Feb-2021 19:02    - \nheartbeat-50m11-Mar-2022 10:07
> 48M\nheartbeat-500m11-Mar-2022 10:07  477M\n\n\n\n"

can anyone please tell me how I can remove tags I used  below method

`filenames <- gsub("<(.|\n)*?>","", filenames)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(filenames, '\n')
[1] "  Index of /data  Index of /dataNameLast modifiedSizeParent Directory  - 2D/24-Feb-2021 15:57 - 3DRefl/13-Oct-2020 16:30 - 3DRhoHV/13-Oct-2020 16:30 - 3DZdr/13-Oct-2020 16:30 - ProbSevere/13-Oct-2020 16:30 - RIDGEII/11-Feb-2021 19:02 - heartbeat-50m11-Mar-2022 10:0748Mheartbeat-500m11-Mar-2022 10:07 477M"
```

Comment: Hi i tested this , its not working :(, getting same output :(

Comment: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<html>\n <head>\n  <title>Index of /data</title>\n </head>\n <body>\n<h1>Index of /data</h1>\n<table><tr><th><a href=\"?C=N;O=D\">Name</a></th><th><a href=\"?C=M;O=A\">Last modified</a></th><th><a href=\"?C=S;O=A\">Size</a></th></tr><tr><th colspan=\"3\"><hr></th></tr>\n<tr><td><a href=\"/\">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align=\"right\"> - </td></tr>\n<tr><td><a href=\"2D/\">2D/</a></td><td align=\"right\">24-Feb-2021 15:57  </td><td align=\"right\">  - </td></tr>\n<tr><td><a href=\"3DRefl/\">3DRefl/</a></td>